# Getting "findLibrary returned null" error in Android-NDK project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I gave up on solving `findLibrary returned null` error in my `Android-NDK` project. Here is the project structure:

```
|_JNI
  |_libsample.so     (pre-compiled)
  |_libsample2.so     (pre-compiled)
  |_Application.mk
  |_Android.mk

|_libs
  |_X86
    |_libsample.so
    |_libsample2.so
```

Source of `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libsample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsample.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libsample2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsample2.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Source of `Application.mk`:

```
APP_ABI := x86
```

Environment variable in `bashrc` file is correctly set up. Location of `ndk path` in Eclipse is correct.

Whenever i am trying to load `Shared_library` i am getting following error:

```
06-06 09:33:36.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load fona from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.fona-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.fona-1]: findLibrary returned null
```

Source for loading shared library in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    System.loadLibrary("libsample");
            ..
            ....
            .....
```

What i am doing wrong here? I found several similar question here but tried everything. Nothing is working :(

## Edit

Source for loading shared library in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    System.loadLibrary("sample");
            ..
            ....
            .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load "sample" and not libsample...

I am also not quiet sure, you should use x86 as the architecture, unless, this is for android-x86 (on virutablbox for instance...)

Furthermore, you could check that your libs are included in your apks !

Comment: @AmitPal - then don't post code which is different than what you tested.  **This answer points out a fatal mistake in your posted code**.  If that code is not what you are testing, then you need to correct your post.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Who said the code was different? Please check nicolas answer and my comment.

Comment: This answer pointed out a problem out something that was wrong with your code which you claimed to have already tried.  If you don't keep your question matching the current state of your code, you cannot receive meaningful assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your generated libs are installed in your apk. To do this, you right click on your eclipse project name, and go into Build Path - Configure Build Path, on the left menu, choose Java Build Path, then click on the Order and Export tab on the right panel, checking the checkbox before your library name and click OK, then clean,rebuild and run you project. 
As Nicolas pointed out load Sample instead of libsample. Choose x86 as TARGET when you create an AVD.